# how to fetch mysql data in plain text

Tags: mysql

i was trying to fetch MySQL  data in node.js project
i was trying to modify code so that authentication can be done through SQL data but their was issue that the function uses only plain text data 
could anyone please tell me how to fetch SQL data in plain text and compare it to the function

Comment: have you got any code to show?

Comment: yes i have  reas it from link http://pastebin.com/zsP5L7Kp

Comment: The main issue in this that sql data i am fetching is in not plain text .If i use simple plain text valules in variable and assign them it then the server get authenticated